# How to add a model instance through another model

Tags: django, django-models, tags, manytomanyfield

Guys I was looking at how I can add a model instance that can be added through another model. like how tags are done. If a model instance doesn't exist add it. if It does exist, don't add, just use the existing one. I wanted to do that with a Category model where if the category exists use the existing one and vice versa.

#Models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text='Name of your company', )
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    categories = models.ManytoManyField(Category, related_name="company", blank=True, null=True, 
                                 on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

#Views

```
class CompanyCreate(CreateView):
    model = Company
    form_class = CompanyForm
    template_name = 'company/form.html'
```

So when one adds a company can add many categories but use the one that already exists. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you take a look for get_or_create() Django function ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: I did it gave me an error, I'll do it again, and get back to you with the actual outcome

Comment: I did it gave me an error, cannot assign "": " Company.categories must be a Category instance. This is after I changed it from many to many to foreign key.